# How to handle moving sources from C to C++ in gcc auto-generated header dependencies?

Tags: gcc, g++, gnu-make

We have a project, which is now slowly migrating from C to C++. It uses `GNU Make` as build system. We use `GCC` -M flags to generate dependencies on headers.

When generating dependencies `GCC` adds source files and all needed headers to dependence list. To work-around header deletion there is -MP flag. But it doesn't fix error when source file moves from .c to .cpp extension (or backwards when switching between branches), because there is still auto-generated dependence on .c, which no more exists.

There are some ways to fix it I came up with, but all seams to be a bit hacky:

1. Always change filename when migrating
2. Generate different name on file with dependencies based on language
3. Rewrite generated dependencies by own script.
4. Add targets to ignore all missing .c/.cpp in dependencies

Did I miss some easy fix?

Small example:

```
-include a.d

%.o: %.c
    gcc -MP -MMD -MF $*.d -MQ $@ -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -MP -MMD -MF $*.d -MQ $@ -c -o $@ $<

a: a.o
    g++ a.o -o a
```

In the case above, if compile a from a.c and than move a.c -> a.cpp

> make: *** No rule to make target 'a.c', needed by 'a.o'.  Stop.

error would be raised. But after clean build will pass normally.

Comment: Show an [MCVE] with the *exact* `Makefile`; without that your question is unclear.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: The solution is to run a full build (so `make clean` then `make`) or to have something which *rewrites* the dependency files

Comment: Well, of course it is, but the purpose of make if to do all this work instead of you, so this solutions not seem to be elegant enough, Also, while the error is quite obvious when you rename file yourself, it's hard to understand what's happening when you receive renaming by git pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option (base `.d` file names on the input file name, not the output file name) seems the one that is most commonly used.  That is, use `-MF $@.d` instead of `-MF $*.d`.

If you currently list the object files as dependencies, you can perhaps switch that to a list of source files from which you generate the list of object files using `$(patsubst …)`.  (This assumes that the source files have regular names or locations which indicate where the object files are going to be used.)  Or you could use `$(wildcard …)` to obtain the list automatically from the source tree, or use a manifest file generated from the checked-in files list from the version control system.

Comment: Wildcard will not solve the problem, because it will include obsolete file with bad dependency.